# R-squared in linear model verses deviance in generalized linear model?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, least-squares, r-squared, deviance

Here's my context for this question: From what I can tell, we cannot run an ordinary least squares regression in R when using weighted data and the `survey` package. Here, we have to use `svyglm()`, which instead runs a generalized linear model (which may be the same thing? I am fuzzy here in terms of what is different).

In OLS and through the `lm()` function, it calculates an R-squared value, the interpretation of which I do understand. However, `svyglm()` does not seem to calculate this and instead gives me a Deviance, which my brief trip around the internet tells me is a goodness-of-fit measure that is interpreted differently than an R-squared.

So I guess I essentially have two questions on which I was hoping to get some direction:

1. Why can we not run OLS in the `survey` package, while it seems that this is possible to do with weighted data in Stata?
2. What is the difference in interpretation between the deviance of a generalized linear model and an r-squared value?

Comment: Welcome to the site, @RichardBlissett, +1 for a good question. OLS regression is a special case of the generalized linear model, where the link function is the identity function & the response distribution is normal (see my answer here: [difference-between-logit-and-probit-models](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20523//30909#30909), for more info). There are 'pseudo-R2's for GLiMs, but they're controversial (see here: [which-pseudo-r2-to-report-for-logistic-regression](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3559/), for more info).

Comment: Thanks so much for your comment (and sorry it took so long for me to respond...I lost this question and had completely forgotten that I didn't put it on SO).

That was an amazing couple of explanations, thanks. I guess my question, then, is this: I assume, then that these statistical packages do not run OLS because there's some fundamental issue with running that with survey-weighted data. I can't seem to figure out, however, what that issue is.

Comment: Deviance is a generalization of variance, and expected deviance is a generalization of R-square. The problem is that there does not seem to be an easy or general answer to expected deviance, see for instance here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/124306/measure-of-explained-variance-for-poisson-glm-log-link-function/180470#180470

Answer (score 3):

> From what I can tell, we cannot run an ordinary least squares
>   regression in R when using weighted data and the `survey` package. Here,
>   we have to use `svyglm()`, which instead runs a generalized linear model
>   (which may be the same thing? I am fuzzy here in terms of what is
>   different).

`svyglm` will give you a linear model if you use `family = gaussian()` which seems to be the default from the [survey vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survey/vignettes/survey.pdf) (in version 3.32-1). See the example where they find the `regmodel`.

It seems that the package just makes sure that you use the correct weights when it calls `glm`. Thus, if your outcome is continuous and you assume that it is normally iid distributed then you should use `family = gaussian()`. The result is a weighted linear model. This answer

> Why can we not run OLS in the `survey` package, while it seems that this
>   is possible to do with weighted data in Stata?

by stating that you indeed can do that with the `survey` package. As for the following question

> What is the difference in interpretation between the deviance of a
>   generalized linear model and an r-squared value?

There is a straight forward formula to get the $R^2$ with `family = gaussian()` as some people have mentioned in the comments. Adding weights does not change anything either as I show below

```
> set.seed(42293888)
> x <- (-4):5
> y <- 2 + x + rnorm(length(x))
> org <- data.frame(x = x, y = y, weights = 1:10)
> 
> # show data and fit model. Notice the R-squared
> head(org) 
   x          y weights
1 -4  0.4963671       1
2 -3 -0.5675720       2
3 -2 -0.3615302       3
4 -1  0.7091697       4
5  0  0.6485203       5
6  1  3.8495979       6
> summary(lm(y ~ x, org, weights = weights))

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x, data = org, weights = weights)

Weighted Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.1693 -0.4463  0.2017  0.9100  2.9667 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   1.7368     0.3514   4.942  0.00113 ** 
x             0.9016     0.1111   8.113 3.95e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 2.019 on 8 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.8916,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.8781 
F-statistic: 65.83 on 1 and 8 DF,  p-value: 3.946e-05

> 
> # make redundant data set with redundant rows
> idx <- unlist(mapply(rep, x = 1:nrow(org), times = org$weights))
> org_redundant <- org[idx, ]
> head(org_redundant)
     x          y weights
1   -4  0.4963671       1
2   -3 -0.5675720       2
2.1 -3 -0.5675720       2
3   -2 -0.3615302       3
3.1 -2 -0.3615302       3
3.2 -2 -0.3615302       3
> 
> # fit model and notice the same R-squared
> summary(lm(y ~ x, org_redundant))

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x, data = org_redundant)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.19789 -0.29506 -0.05435  0.33131  2.36610 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  1.73680    0.13653   12.72   <2e-16 ***
x            0.90163    0.04318   20.88   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.7843 on 53 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.8916,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.8896 
F-statistic: 436.1 on 1 and 53 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

> 
> # glm gives you the same with family = gaussian()  
> # just compute the R^2 from the deviances. See 
> #   https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/46358/81865
> fit <- glm(y ~ x, family = gaussian(), org_redundant)
> fit$coefficients
(Intercept)           x 
  1.7368017   0.9016347 
> 1 - fit$deviance / fit$null.deviance
[1] 0.8916387
```

The deviance is just the sum of square errors when you use `family = gaussian()`.

## Caveats

I assume that you want a linear model from your question. Further, I have never used the `survey` package but quickly scanned through it and made assumptions about what it does which I state in my answer.