# What is the null model for a four-way contingency table?

Tags: r, contingency-tables, log-linear

I'm working through [this tutorial](http://ww2.coastal.edu/kingw/statistics/R-tutorials/loglin.html) on the `Titanic` data in `R`, a four-way contingency table, and I'm unclear as to what is the NULL model in this context?

```
> data(Titanic)
> ftable(Titanic)
                   Survived  No Yes
Class Sex    Age                   
1st   Male   Child            0   5
             Adult          118  57
      Female Child            0   1
             Adult            4 140
2nd   Male   Child            0  11
             Adult          154  14
      Female Child            0  13
             Adult           13  80
3rd   Male   Child           35  13
             Adult          387  75
      Female Child           17  14
             Adult           89  76
Crew  Male   Child            0   0
             Adult          670 192
      Female Child            0   0
             Adult            3  20
```

The following would be the *model of (mutual) independence* for the Titanic data:

```
> (x <- glm(Freq ~ Sex + Class + Age + Survived, poisson, data.frame(Titanic)))

Call:  glm(formula = Freq ~ Sex + Class + Age + Survived, family = poisson, 
    data = data.frame(Titanic))

Coefficients:
(Intercept)    SexFemale     Class2nd     Class3rd    ClassCrew     AgeAdult  SurvivedYes  
     2.1482      -1.3037      -0.1313       0.7758       1.0018       2.9545      -0.7399  

Degrees of Freedom: 31 Total (i.e. Null);  25 Residual
Null Deviance:      4953 
Residual Deviance: 1244     AIC: 1385
> sum(residuals(x, type = "pearson")^2)  ## Pearson's X^2 score test
[1] 1637.445
```

This little is straightforward. I get confused though as to what is the difference between the "Null" model above with 31 df, and the mutual independence model with 25 df.

Compounding the confusion is that `summary` and `chisq.test` seem to be doing different things:

```
> summary(Titanic)
Number of cases in table: 2201 
Number of factors: 4 
Test for independence of all factors:
    Chisq = 1637.4, df = 25, p-value = 0
    Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
> chisq.test(Titanic, correct=F)

    Chi-squared test for given probabilities

data:  Titanic
X-squared = 8335.723, df = 31, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

One will report results for the 25 df model, the other for the 31 df. `?chisq.test` says: "the hypothesis tested is whether the population probabilities [are] equal". While `?summary.table` "performs a chi-squared test for independence of factors (note that the function chisq.test currently only handles 2-d tables)."

So, what is the difference between the *Chi-squared test for given [equal] probabilities* and the *Test for independence of all factors*? And, more importantly, what is the null model here, and what does it stand for?  (Namely in the context of the *independence model* and the *saturated model*...)

---

This question is somewhat related to [Test GLM model using null and model deviances](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/141177/test-glm-model-using-null-and-model-deviances/141179#141179)...