# Poisson GAM - model never fits when using residual deviance test (chi squared)

Tags: r, chi-squared-test, poisson-distribution, generalized-additive-model

If I were to fit an example GAM model using mgcv:

```
m1 <- gam(cases~s(salary,bs="cs",k=50)+s(age,bs="cs",k=50)+
            s(density,bs="cs",k=50)+
            s(longitude,latitude,bs="ds",k=100),
          data=example,family=poisson(),method="REML")
```

And if

- `summary(m1)` shows all smooth terms are significant
- adjusted R-squared is 0.999
- deviance explained is 99%
- `gam.check(m1)` shows all `k` are penalized appropriately
- the QQ plot looks to follow the line (bar a few points straying off
  on the tails)
- resids vs linear predictor plot doesn't look like it's trending
- histogram of residuals doesn't have too fat tails and follows closely to a gaussian distribution

Given all of this, why is it that a Chi Squared test on the deviance residuals suggest that the model fit is bad?

```
pchisq(m1$deviance,df=m1$df.residual,lower.tail=F)
```

which gives something close to zero (e.g. 1.234e-20).

`summary(m1)`:

```
Parametric coefficients:
  Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) 2.697446   0.003262   698.2   <2e-16 ***
  ---
  Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                        edf   Ref.df  Chi.sq p-value    
  s(salary)             19.132 49.000 5793.49  <2e-16 ***
  s(age)                29.933 49.000  393.71  <2e-16 ***
  s(density)            36.198 49.000  354.83  <2e-16 ***
  s(longitude,latitude) 88.230 96.095 2545.63  <2e-16 ***
  ---
  Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.999   Deviance explained = 99.6%
-REML = 7402.2  Scale est. = 1         n = 2155
```

Furthermore, should there be a "next course of action"? Like adding adding in variation of a covariate across space (e.g. ti(longitude, latitude, age)). If so, should this be done for each and every pair of covariates (salary,density etc.).

Comment: Please the thread here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/141177/ I think it answers your query. Also if it doesn't can you please add the output of the `summary()`?

Comment: @usεr11852 added `summary()`. I have seen that thread before, they suggest that a `1-pchisq` needs to be done or, equivalently, set `lower.tail=FALSE`. Yet my p-value is still close to zero. Are you/they are suggesting that `pchisq(m1$deviance,df=m1$df.residual,lower.tail=F)` is wrong, and that I need to get the difference between null deviance and model deviance? If so, where do I get the null deviance? The model `m1` is the first model that I am using.

Comment: So if my p-value is close to zero, it implies that `m1` is no better than the null model (so I interpret this as not exactly a good fit). If so, why does the bullet points outlined above suggest that the model looks good - seems contradictory?

Comment: The null model here is `m0 <- glm(cases~1,data=cases, family=poisson)`. (Also, reasonably we probably want to `ML` to our GAM rather than `REML` to make the comparison fair). Then we just do `pchisq(deviance(m0) - deviance(m1), df=m0$df.residual - m1$df.residual, lower.tail=FALSE)`. Notice that the latest result being "zero" is "good thing"; the p-value is exceptional small, so we can reject the null hypothesis that the two models are equal.

Comment: Thank you for this information, I consolidated my main comment and some additional points to a post; please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The null model here is `m0 <- glm(y~1,data=cases, family=poisson)`. (Also, reasonably we probably want to `ML` to our GAM rather than `REML` to make the comparison fair). Then we just do `pchisq(deviance(m0) - deviance(m1), df=m0$df.residual - m1$df.residual, lower.tail=FALSE)`. Notice that this latest result being "zero" is "good thing"; the p-value is exceptional small, so we can reject the null hypothesis that the two models are equal.

I think the "next course of action" should be to justify why adjusted $R^2$ is so high (0.999). While counter-intuitive, I think that such extremely high values of $R^2$ should be scrutinised as to "*why*" they are so good; in effect this suggests we have no sampling errors, no unobserved confounders, no competing exposures, absolutely nothing aside the deterministic variation due to our observed features. Yeah, I have been to the Stats rodeo enough times to know there are bulls there...

Comment: Yes, the p-value is now small indicating that the two models are not equal. But, does this also indicate that `m1` is a good fit? Or is it a situation where the `pchisq` test used here is for telling me whether `m1` is either bad or not? i.e. large p-value means the two models are practically equal and thus it's a bad fit, but small p-value means that `m1` is NOT a bad fit (but can range anywhere from ok fit to amazing fit)?

Comment: The p-value itself it suggests we have some significant interaction between at least one of our predictor variables and our response variable; *here* `m1` is not a bad fit compared to `m0`, it is obvious that some signal is captured, ergo `m1` is a better model than `m0` but we cannot really quantify by how much as you correctly recognise. It would be possible to have a "worse model" (with a significant $p$-value from `pchisq` compared to `m0`) if the $R^2$ was negative or something else pathological like that but clearly this is not the case here.

Comment: So I guess I was using pchisq for the wrong reasons (being to test whether `m1` was a good fit to the data) and should instead rely on other methods to determine the goodness of fit for this poisson GAM model?

Comment: Yes, you got it right now. :) `m1` is "better" than `m0` in terms of goodness-of-fit (GoF) for this data if that is the question; that said, assessing the goodness-of-fit (in practical terms: predictions) of any regression model cannot be a dichotomous decision as rejecting or failing to reject a null hypothesis. For example, providing a cross-validated estimate of RMSE or MAE would be much more relevant. But that is a rather large topic suitable for a separate question. :)

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help!

Comment: Cool! I am glad I could help!