# Is it ok to flip the independent, dependent variable in one-way ANOVA?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova

Consider this scenario:  scientists hypothesize that a particular disease occurs
when levels of a particular hormone are high. They gather data: 1000 people with the disease,
1000 without, and measure their hormone levels.

Assuming the data has normal distribution, the scientists can do a t-test or one-way anova to test if the difference in hormone levels between the disease and non-disease group is significantly different from zero. (I guess this would be a one-sided t-test).
In R, the Anova would be expressed like

```
model <- lm( HormoneLevel ~ Disease, ...)
```

where Disease is 0/1 according to disease|non-disease, and HormoneLevel is a continuous value (amount per litre or something).

HOWEVER, can the test also be done in the other direction, with HormoneLevel as the independent variable?

```
model <- lm( Disease ~ HormoneLevel, ...)
```

Perhaps this makes more sense conceptually as a regression, since the scientists believe that the hormone level may be a cause of the disease.

So the question:  is it valid and desirable to switch the dependent and independent variables in this way?
If so, are there restrictions on when it can be done?

Comment: If you want to build a valid model for Disease ~ HormoneLevel , you might use logistic regression, such as glm(Disease ~ HormoneLevel, family = binomial(link="logit")).

Comment: ok, yes.   However my question is more about the validity and advantage/disadvantage (if valid) of flipping the independent and dependent variables.

Comment: As you say, if you think that the hormone causes the disease or that the hormone can predict the disease, then the model Disease ~ Hormone makes sense.  There's no reason to think that Hormone ~ Disease is the default or natural model to use.  If there's no prediction or causation intended, correlation could be used instead.

Comment: Thank you.  So if we use a logistic regression, we can get a prediction of Disease from Hormone, divide our data into training (,validation), test, and report some sort of accuracy.  But is there a way to report a p-value or "significance", as is possible by formulating it in the other direction?

Comment: logistic regression in R gives the usual GLM output - including asymptotic p-values for individual variables and null and residual deviance, from which an asymptotic [overall test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood-ratio_test#Distribution:_Wilks%E2%80%99_theorem) could be performed. This is covered in most statistical treatments of generalized linear models, and in several questions on site e.g. this one - https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/108995/interpreting-residual-and-null-deviance-in-glm-r