# LL Null custom implementation

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, likelihood

I need to recreate some of the results of R in a python library, specifically LL-Null. I know that it describes

> The null deviance shows how well the response is predicted by the model with nothing but an intercept.

as per [Interpreting Residual and Null Deviance in GLM R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/108995/interpreting-residual-and-null-deviance-in-glm-r)

## Question

Does this mean that I use an already-fit model and 0 out all the non-intercept weights? If not, how would this go? I need to implement it custom for an internal library I am building

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation describes a null model that is just an intercept, without any features; in other words, the null model estimates the intercept that minimizes the loss.

For instance, in an OLS model, you can show that the value $\beta_0$ that minimizes the square error $\sum_i (y_i - \beta_0)^2$ is $\beta_0=\bar{y}$ the sample mean of $y$.

It's generally the case that the sample mean of $y$ is different from the intercept of a regression model that includes one or more features/independent variables.

Comment: Ahh, gotcha! So, you're basically saying "take the average" of the output variable?

Comment: Not necessarily. Different models will have different losses or parameterizations, such which might imply that the optimal value of the intercept in the null model takes an alternative form. Your question references GLMs, for instance.

Comment: Hmm, could you elaborate on that? Say I've got GLMs all using least-squares. How would I derive what the null model for each of them? E.g a Poisson, a sigmoid, probit, etc. Do you know of any articles or resources?

Comment: The R documentation for GLMs, which you cite, contains four references.