# Is the ALRE method of standardization/rescaling appropriate for proportion data?

Tags: forecasting, error

I have data in which groups of experts make proportion estimates.

I've been encouraged to use the ALRE method of scoring the error of these estimates. I found [an article](http://www.plosone.org/article/info%3Adoi%2F10.1371%2Fjournal.pone.0022998) which describes this method:

[image]

As I understand it, the purpose of the ALRE method is to obtain a measure of error that is not dominated by single predictions that are wildly wrong. For example, answers to a question like "What is the distance (in km) between the Mars and Neptune?" could be wildly wrong.

However, all my data is bounded by 0 and 1 and thus I'm not sure if this measure is appropriate for me. If this is not a suitable measure for my sort of data, what should I use?

The observed values are 1s and 0s in some of my data sets. In some of my other data sets the observed values are also proportions.

Comment: Are the observed values that you have 1s or 0s? Or are they proportions too? I don't know this ALRE but if you have a predicted probability distribution, any proper scoring rule should work fine. See e.g. my answer here http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/71720/error-metrics-for-cross-validating-poisson-models/71936#71936

Comment: The observed values are 1s and 0s in some of my data sets. In some of my other data sets the observed values are also proportions. This is certainly something I should have mentioned in the OP, so I have edited it. Could you explain a little further what you mean by any proper scoring rule being fine if I have a predicted probability distribution?