# Sum of squared Poisson probability masses

Tags: poisson-distribution, entropy

Let $(p_k)_{k=0, \dots, \infty}$ denote the probability masses of a [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) with parameter $\lambda$. I'm looking for the sum of their squares,
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty p_k^2,$$
as a function of $\lambda$. In other words I am interested in (the exponential of) the *second-order [Renyi entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9nyi_entropy)* of a Poisson distribution.

Background:

- I'd like to use this to evaluate [Brier and spherical scores](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/71936/1352).
- [Czado et al. (2009)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1111/j.1541-0420.2009.01191.x) write that this expression can be evaluated analytically, but don't give further information, and I'm kind of stuck.
- No, this is not homework, although I imagine it could be ;-) Any hints or pointers to literature would be almost as much appreciated as a full solution.
- [Here is the analogous question for the Negative Binomial distribution.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/162430/1352)

Comment: This question appears in many forms.  Answers can be found by a search for [skellam](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=Skellam).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't hesitate to use [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) to get the sum of a series. Or do you need a mathematical proof ?

[image]

This gives $\exp(-2\lambda)I_0(2\lambda)$. 
The link to the documentation of the Bessel function $I_0$ is [this one](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BesselI.html).

Actually the proof here would just mean the series representation of $I_0$.

If you want to use R to evaluate this Bessel function, you can do it with the help of the `gsl` package:

```
> library(gsl)
> lambda <- 1
> exp(-2*lambda)*bessel_I0(2*lambda)
[1] 0.3085083
> sum(dpois(0:100, lambda)^2)
[1] 0.3085083
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. What would be the advantage of using `gsl::bessel_I0()` rather than `base::besselI(nu=0)`?

Comment: @StephanKolassa I didn't know `base::besselI`. I don't know whether one is better than the other.