# Is this a common formula to find pseudo R-squared for this GLM?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, r-squared

I'm trying to figure out if this common pseudo R-squared formula is acceptable for the GLM I am running. Here is the code and formula:

```
m1<- glm((AdjustedActivity3+1)~HDtype, family = Gamma(link = log), data = q2)
```

**McFaden's pseudo r2 formula:**

```
1-(m1$deviance/m1$null.deviance)
```

I wonder: does the Gamma family have a specific formula for an R-squared value in this case, or is McFaden's usage generally accepted?

Comment: This Q&A http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11676/pseudo-r-squared-formula-for-glms?rq=1 has many useful links to resources for and against pseudo $R^2$.