# Trying to understand partial R-squared

Tags: r-squared, partial-correlation

I'm trying to understand partial R-squared as computed by package `rsq`. See the reproducible example on the standard data set:

```R
require(rsq)
data(esoph)
model1 <- glm(cbind(ncases, ncontrols) ~ agegp + tobgp * alcgp,
              data = esoph, family = binomial)

attach(esoph)
rsq(model1)
# [1] 0.826124
rsq.partial(model1)
$variable
#[1] "agegp"       "tobgp"       "alcgp"       "tobgp:alcgp"
#
#$partial.rsq
#[1]  0.6548246836256900182960 -0.0000000000000006661338  0.0000000000000000000000  0.1456091052940046148834
rsq.partial(model1, adj = TRUE)
#$adjustment
#[1] TRUE
#
#$variable
#[1] "agegp"       "tobgp"       "alcgp"       "tobgp:alcgp"
#
#$partial.rsq
#[1]  0.6290653316574579267950 -0.0000000000000006661338  0.0000000000000000000000  0.0308401791394680158120
detach(esoph)
```

Here, the partial R-squared for the first variable `agegp` seems too high. Just look at the deviance anova table:

```R
anova(model1)
#             Df Deviance Resid. Df Resid. Dev
# NULL                           87    227.241
# agegp        5   88.128        82    139.112
# tobgp        3   19.085        79    120.028
# alcgp        3   66.054        76     53.973
# tobgp:alcgp  9    6.489        67     47.484

cat("pseudo R2 agegp: ", 1-139.112/model1$null.deviance, "\n")
pseudo R2 agegp:  0.3878206
```

So from the deviance table, the [pseudo R-squared](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/11676/5509) corresponding to the `agegp` variable is 0.3878. This also corresponds to `rsq()` and `rsq.partial` called on a model with only `agegp` variable:

```R
model1 <- glm(cbind(ncases, ncontrols) ~ agegp, data = esoph, family = binomial)
attach(esoph)
rsq(model1)
# [1] 0.3791795
rsq.partial(model1)
#$adjustment
#[1] FALSE
#
#$variable
#[1] "agegp"
#
#$partial.rsq
#[1] 0.3791795
detach(esoph)
```

So why is the partial R-squared coefficient claimed to be 0.655 (or 0.629 adjusted)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The R-square compares two models: a full model and a reduced model. You compute the pseudo R-square twice but you change both the full model and the reduced model. It is hard to compare two R-squares when there are four models involved.

There are several definitions of the pseudo R-square. Let's take the Efron's definition since it is easy to compute and on this problem it gives similar "unintuitive" results as the measure used by `rsq` by default. Efron's pseudo R-square is `1 - SSE.full / SSE.reduced`. When you change both the full model and the reduced model, you change both the nominator and the denominator of the ratio. The computation is below but in short `agegp` explains 35% of the total variability but 60% of the variability left unexplained after taking into account `tobgp` and `alcgp`.

More about pseudo R-squares: https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/faq/general/faq-what-are-pseudo-r-squareds/.

First let's explicitly define the full and reduced models that are compared in your question.

```r
library("rsq")

data(esoph)
attach(esoph)

# Full model with all three predictors.
# (Technically, three main predictors + interaction.)
fit.x1x2x3 <- glm(
  cbind(ncases, ncontrols) ~ agegp + tobgp * alcgp,
  family = binomial
)
# Reduced model with only agegp.
fit.x1 <- glm(
  cbind(ncases, ncontrols) ~ agegp,
  family = binomial
)
# Reduced model with agegp removed.
fit.x2x3 <- glm(
  cbind(ncases, ncontrols) ~ tobgp * alcgp,
  family = binomial
)
# Null model with no predictors.
fit.null <- glm(
  cbind(ncases, ncontrols) ~ 1,
  family = binomial
)

# The `rsq` function has 5 methods for computing the R-squared.
# The default is "v" (variance-function-based R-squared)
# but I will use "sse" since it is easy to compute.
# It gives similar results in this case.
type <- "sse"

# Computation 1: 
# What is the "value" of adding agegp to a model which includes all other predictors?

rsq.partial(fit.x1x2x3, type = type)$partial.rsq
#> [1] 0.6193845 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.1541909
rsq.partial(fit.x1x2x3, fit.x2x3, type = type)$partial.rsq
#> [1] 0.6193845

# So the partial R-square measures the additional variation explained by agegp,
# after adjustment for the other predictors.

# Note: Now it is clear why the partial R-squared for tobgp and alcgp are 0.
# By default, `rsq` comes up with reduced models by dropping each predictor
# and leaving the others in. However, it is a bit silly to remove the main
# effect for tobgp or alcgp but leave their interaction in.

# Computation 2: 
# What is the "value" of agegp for predicting the response given no other information?

rsq.partial(fit.x1, type = type)$partial.rsq
#> [1] 0.3515373
rsq.partial(fit.x1, fit.null, type = type)$partial.rsq
#> [1] 0.3515373
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

And let's compute Efron's R-square explicitly to show that `agegp` explains 35% of the total variability but 60% of the variability left unexplained after taking into account `tobgp` and `alcgp`.

```r
library("modelr")
library("tidyverse")

list(
  x1x2x3 = fit.x1x2x3,
  x2x3 = fit.x2x3,
  x1 = fit.x1,
  null = fit.null
) %>%
  map_dfr(~ add_predictions(esoph, ., var = "yhat", type = "response"),
          .id = "model") %>%
  mutate(
    n = ncases + ncontrols,
    y = ncases / n
  ) %>%
  group_by(model) %>%
  summarise(
    SSE = sum(n * (y - yhat)^2)
  )
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>   model    SSE
#>   <chr>  <dbl>
#> 1 null   27.5 
#> 2 x1     17.8 
#> 3 x1x2x3  5.10
#> 4 x2x3   13.4

# 1 - SSE.x1x2x3 / SSE.x2x3
1 - 5.10 / 13.4
#> [1] 0.619403
# 1 - SSE.x1 / SSE.null
1 - 17.8 / 27.5
#> [1] 0.3527273
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This explains something. But my main question still stays: how "the value of adding agegp" can be 0.65? That seems too high, considering that the total variability explained by `agegp` is 0.379 (last two commands). The `agegp` raises the rsq from `rsq(fit.x2x3)` = 0.496 up to `rsq(fit.x1x2x3)` = 0.826, so can the value of adding it be 0.65? I must miss something key here...

Comment: It is true that the total variability explained by `agegp` is ~35%. The confusion is about the meaning of the ~65% -- it is the variability which `agegp` explains after adjusting for the other two variables. So there is no contradiction.

Comment: Thanks, so for me the essential understanding of how the 0.65 is possible is this: `(rsq(fit.x1x2x3) - rsq(fit.x2x3))/(1 - rsq(fit.x2x3))` which corresponds to the definition of `1 - deviance(fit.x1x2x3)/deviance(fit.x2x3)` (just to illustrate principle, different measure of variance was used by `rsq`). This can be converted to `%incMSE` from randomForest and also to partial correlation coefficient. Thanks for help!

Comment: Yes, I think you are right that it should be similar to `%incMSE` since `%incMSE` is computed by permuting, i.e. "dropping" each variable, in turn.