# Is the percent of total deviance explained a useful model summary?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, r-squared, deviance

My question is regarding the interpretation of the percent of deviance explained (and other $R^2$ anaologs or pseudo $R^2$ values for GLMs.

Is this a meaningful summary statistic for models other than Gaussian?  That is, is it at least as meaningful/useful as the $R^2$ statistic in the typical OLS regression model.  (We'll work under the assumption that $R^2$ is useful summary measure in an OLS framework).

Of course, percent of deviance explained is equivalent to the $R^2$ value if the link is Gaussian.

```
fit1<-glm( rating~1,
           data=attitude,family = gaussian)
fit2<-glm( rating~complaints+privileges+learning+raises+critical+advance,
           data=attitude,family = gaussian)

(deviance(fit1)-deviance(fit2))/deviance(fit1)
```

[1] 0.732602

```
summary(lm( rating~complaints+privileges+learning+raises+critical+advance,
            data=attitude))
```

Multiple R-squared: 0.7326

Is there a similarly meaningful interpretation of the percent of deviance explained from models from other GLM families, like binomial (logit/probit) or poisson regression?  Or, does the change in link function and the characteristics of the model/response affect the interpretation of this statistic?

Comment: Is this: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/mult_pkg/faq/general/psuedo_rsquareds.htm helpful, or do you mean something else?

Comment: Indeed.  The deviance R^2 from my question is the same as McFadden's measure.  My question is really about interpretation of the deviance R^2 for non-Gaussian models.  With a normal link it corresponds to SSR/SST and thus has a clean and neat interpretation.  Is this true of other families?  Do the results depend on the link used and the characteristics of the response?

Comment: Walking down another path, I stumbled onto a very clear answer to my question in by @probabilityislogic in the thread at: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3559/logistic-regression-which-pseudo-r-squared-measure-is-the-one-to-report-cox

Comment: Could you re-post your comment as an answer to your own question if it covers everything you wanted?  Then you can accept your answer, and this won't appear as an unanswered question.

Comment: The general deviance based R2, 1-residual deviance/null deviance, applies to any GLM with any family & link function. McFadden's was originally defined for logistic regression (where the log-likelihood of a saturated model=0) and in that case the above formula is correct, but the generically correct version would be 1-residual deviance/null deviance, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/359906/is-r-squared-truly-an-invalid-metric-for-non-linear-models/359997?noredirect=1#comment771122_359997

Comment: Without having to fit your model plus an intercept only model & a fully saturated model you can also calculated the R2 from the last iteration of the IRLS algo, which is just a weighted least squares regression - see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/412580/why-is-r2-not-reported-for-glms-based-on-last-iteration-of-irls-weighted-least-s