# Comparing $R^2$ between Gaussian GLM with identity link and with $\log$ link

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, r-squared, logarithm, model-comparison

It is [known](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/279479) that $R^2$ should not be compared between two regressions where one uses features $X_1,\dots ,X_n$ to predict $Y$ and the other uses those same features to predict $\log(Y)$.

However, this relied on taking the logarithm before taking the expected value.

If we consider two GLMs with Gaussian conditional distributions, one linearly modeling $\mathbb E[Y\vert X=x]$ and another linearly modeling $\log\left(\mathbb E[Y\vert X=x]\right)$, is the comparison of $R^2$ values still illegitimate?

Comment: I wasn't planing to post a self-answer, but as I wrote the question and included my suspicions, I began to realize that I believed my suspicions to be right. Nonetheless, I welcome any other thoughts on this matter and am willing (eager, even) to accept an answer by another member.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**LEGITIMATE!**

We are assessing the performance of two models of $\mathbb E[Y\vert X=x]$:

1. $\mathbb E[Y\vert X=x] = X\hat\beta_{ols}$
2. $\mathbb E[Y\vert X=x] = e^{X\hat\beta_{glm}} \iff \log\left(\mathbb E[Y\vert X=x]\right) = X\hat\beta_{glm}$

We know that $R^2$ in the second case [lacks the usual "proportion of variance explained"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/551915/interpreting-nonlinear-regression-r2) interpretation that is convenient, but if we [view $R^2$ as a function of the square loss](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/584403/247274), everything is okay if we are concerned about square loss (keeping in mind [the usual concerns](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/13317) about $R^2$).

This is no different from evaluating any other two models of the same data and comparing them on square loss (or some function of square loss like $RMSE$ or $R^2$).