# log and negetive prediction

Tags: predictive-models, validation, logarithm

Because my model had a negative prediction, I used the same log method for it, but a problem occurred to me when I do this method, it is true that r2 also reaches 99, but the results of cross validation do not match with the results of the model, now when I do not get log r2 drops to 82, but the results of cross validation are consistent with the results of the model. Do you know a way that I can reach r2 99 and the results of cross validation are consistent with the results of the model?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What log method did you use, and why did you use it?

Comment: thank you so much im so sorry im not an expert in ml so probably i say something wrong my model predict drug dose as a negative value  so i run this code           
'model = LinearRegression()
y_train_log=np.log(y_train)
y_test_log=np.log(y_test)
y_val_log=np.log(y_val)
model.fit(X_train,y_train_log)
test_pred = np.exp(model.predict(X_test))
train_pred =np.exp(model.predict(X_train))
val_pred=np.exp(model.predict(X_val))'

Comment: Why shouldn’t the model predictions be negative? Sure, it makes no physical sense, but there is no mathematical restriction that forces non-negative predictions.

Comment: so you say that  should remove log? but it decrease my r2 :(

Comment: $R^2$ is not comparable before and after the log transformation. If you want to force positive values, [you can apply a link function in a generalized linear model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/591117/comparing-r2-between-gaussian-glm-with-identity-link-and-with-log-link/591118#591118). $//$ However, when you make a negative prediction after taking the log, doesn’t that mean that your predicted drug dose is $e$ raised to that negative value, since the prediction is a logarithm?

Comment: thank you so much i got it thanks 

Comment: There’s more to it than just raising $e$ to the prediction value.

Comment:  oh I didn't know this I appreciate that

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.