# Getting an equivalent of R-squared for simple univariate regression done with structural equation modeling

Tags: regression, r, structural-equation-modeling, lavaan, univariate

I need to calculate a very simple regression model `outcome ~  predictor`. To treat missings, I have to use FIML and also I need bootstrapping. Since the `lavaan` package in R provides both, I used this code:

```
model <- sem('outcome ~  predictor', data = data, missing = "FIML", se="BOOTSTRAP", bootstrap = 2000, fixed.x = F)
summary(model)
```

Unfortunately, in this structural equation modeling approach, no $R^2$ or adjusted $R^2$ is available in the output. Can someone tell me how I can obtain an equivalent measure that indicates an effect size?
If there's a simpler approach than using `lavaan` which provides FIML, bootstrapping, and effect size output for an univariate regression? That would be even better.

Comment: Try ````inspect(model, "rsquare")````

Comment: Or `summary(model, rsquare=TRUE)`.  See the `class?lavaan` help page for more `summary()` arguments for lavaan-class objects.

Comment: Thank you, both suggestions work. Only adjusted R2 isn't available, but that's not that important.

Comment: Adjusted $R^2$ is going to be funky for a complex model. The usual adjusted $R^2$ considers the degrees of freedom to use [unbiased variance estimates](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/595469/247274). I don’t know structural models, but do you have a way to calculate the degrees of freedom?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand at all why you need a SEM for this model. If you are using a simple regression, why not just simply use OLS? Seems the only reason this was employed, based off the question, was to deal with missingness and bootstrapping. Both can be accomplished without relying on a complicated SEM (such as using multiple imputation and bootstrapped estimates), which may not be important for your use case.

##### Edit

My point was not that the SEM itself is complicated. As I already noted, it is quite straightforward here. The only real thing I saw was an overcomplication of how to obtain everything for the regression if it is straightforwardly accomplished using OLS. But coming back to this question, I suppose this approach would make sense if, as jsakaluk noted, one is committed to using FIML and wants some simpler code. As noted in the above comments, one can easily obtain the $R^2$ with the code `inspect(model, "rsquare")`.

Comment: What, exactly, is complicated about this hypothetical SEM? The model itself is simple. The code gives the user exactly what they want (model specification + model fitting + missing data treatment + bootstrapping), all in one line of code. Since you mention OLS, is it mostly a matter of different properties of each estimator? And if so, I'm curious what differences you're attuned to that seem that large/the complexity introduce that substantial, vs. the other streamlining benefits of using lavaan in this instance?

Comment: Yes, I support @jsakaluk: my advicer for statistics recommended FIML because it's so straight forward and easy in comparison to multiple imputation. Therefore I chose a SEM framework.

Comment: @jsakaluk see edit.

Comment: I read @Madamadam's question as after an alternative/simpler approach that would still provide FIML/bootstrapping, vs. merely describing that lavaan provides these features (as an aside to requesting an alternative). And so, I get that if one just wanted a generic regression, the additions of FIML and bootstrapping would seem "extra". But in this case--and if my understanding of madamadam's needs are correct--FIML and bootstrapping seem germane to the OP's question, and therefore, an answer would need to provide an alternative approach that still maintains these features.

Comment: Yes, it's essential for me to get FIML and bootstrapping, if someone can show, how to get it with a simpler framework like lm(), that would be great.