# Why is it futile to use the deviance as a goodness-of-fit measure for Bernoulli data?

Tags: logistic, goodness-of-fit, bernoulli-distribution, deviance

In [Ordinal Data Modelling](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=6-Y8OL3sW14C&pg=PA102&lpg=PA102&dq=deviance%20of%20a%20%22bernoulli%22%20model?%20goodness%20of%20fit&source=bl&ots=kb3FoEbN30&sig=gJ28_j0CN8-WsFoYp4gDrL2eooA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=SsFhUe3YL-Wa0QWTo4CwBg&ved=0CDsQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=deviance%20of%20a%20%22bernoulli%22%20model?%20goodness%20of%20fit&f=false) by Johson & Albert, page 102-103:

> For Bernoulli observations [...] the asymptotic chi-squared
>   distribution of the deviance statistic may not pertain. Indeed, for
>   the linear logistic models with Bernoulli observations, the deviance
>   function can be expresses solely as a function of the MLE of the
>   regression parameter, **which demonstrates the futility of using this
>   statistic to measure goodness of fit for such data**.

Could someone kindly explain what this means, please?

Comment: You might find this thread helpful: [which pseudo r2 measure is the one to report for logistic regression?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3559/).

Answer (score 2):

I am reiterating from lecture notes I have on the subject.

The issue is the log-likelihood function for the saturated model is always zero when dealing with a binary distribution. 
In the case of that $m_j$ = 1, the log likelihood is
log(L) = $\Sigma_i$ =[$y_i$log($\theta$($x_i$)) + (1 - $y_i$)log(1-$\theta$($x_i$)) + log(${1\choose y_i}$))

If $y_i$ = 0: then you can input it into the above equation and find that the sum is equal to zero

If $y_i$ = 1: then you can input it into the above equation and fine that the sum is also equal to zero.

So in the case where $m_i$ = 1, the deviance between the saturated model and the current model depends *only* on log($L_m$). Recalling that deviance is defined as 
$G^2$ = 2[log($L_s$) - log($L_m$)].

Deviance doesn't proved an assessment of the goodness-of-fit of the model! (The exclamation is in the notes). It also does not have a $\chi^2$ distribution.

However, we *can* use deviance to compare two models; the difference between two deviance still has an approximate $\chi^2$ distribution.