# Variation explained in ordinal logistic regression models

Tags: r, regression, logistic, r-squared, ordered-logit

I have made these three ordinal logistic regression models:

```
model1 <-  polr(as.factor(carb) ~ mpg,  Hess = T, mtcars)
model2 <-  polr(as.factor(carb) ~ hp,   Hess = T, mtcars)
model3 <-  polr(as.factor(carb) ~ drat, Hess = T, mtcars)
```

To figure out if the models are a good fit to the data, I calculated the proportion of variation explained like this:

```
model_null <-  polr(as.factor(carb) ~ 1, Hess = T, mtcars)

1-(model1$deviance/model_null$deviance)
0.1512784
1-(model2$deviance/model_null$deviance)
0.2520109
1-(model3$deviance/model_null$deviance)
0.003453936
```

Questions:

1. Why doesn't summary give null deviance?
2. Have I calculated the proportion of variation explained correctly?
3. Am I right in saying `model1` and `model3` explain little variation in `carb`, but `model2` explains 25% of the variation in `carb`?

Comment: There is a legitimate question of whether 'variance explained' is really a meaningful quantity to wonder about for GLiMs, you may want to read through this thread: [Which pseudo-$R^2$ to report for logistic regression](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/3559/).

Answer (score 5):

Even for logistic regression with a dichotomous DV, there is no exact equivalent of $R^2$ (proportion of variance explained) nor any consensus on which approximation is best. Here is [Paul Allison's explanation](http://www.statisticalhorizons.com/r2logistic). However, the version Allison likes best is that of Tjur:

> But there’s another $R^2$, recently proposed by Tjur (2009), that I’m
>   inclined to prefer over McFadden’s. It has a lot of intuitive appeal,
>   its upper bound is 1.0, and it’s closely related to $R^2$ definitions for
>   linear models. It’s also easy to calculate.
>
> The definition is very simple. For each of the two categories of the
>   dependent variable, calculate the mean of the predicted probabilities
>   of an event. Then, take the difference between those two means. That’s
>   it!

Unfortunately, with more than two categories, there will be more than one difference; perhaps, however, some statistic based on this could be used. However, Allison is not optimistic about this:

> Another potential complaint is that the Tjur $R^2$ cannot be easily
>   generalized to ordinal or nominal logistic regression. For McFadden
>   and Cox-Snell, the generalization is straightforward.

Of those two, Allison now prefers McFadden:

> Here are the details. Logistic regression is, of course, estimated by
>   maximizing the likelihood function. Let $L_0$ be the value of the
>   likelihood function for a model with no predictors, and let $L_M$ be the
>   likelihood for the model being estimated. McFadden’s $R^2$ is defined as
>
> $R^2_{McF} = 1\ –\ \ln(L_M) / \ln(L_0)$

Comment: UCLA's statistics help site also has an excellent overview of pseudo-$R^2$s [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20140529032520/http://statistics.ats.ucla.edu/stat/mult_pkg/faq/general/Psuedo_RSquareds.htm).