# Why could pseudo $R$-squared (pseudo $R^2$) increase when I remove variables?

Tags: multinomial-distribution, r-squared

I have a multinomial logistic regression with $11$ independent variables. When I remove variables, the pseudo $R$-squared increases.

Isn't this not supposed to happen? Why could this be happening?

Comment: Can you specify precisely what you mean by pseudo-$R^2$? I've seen a few different quantities called that.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3559/which-pseudo-r2-measure-is-the-one-to-report-for-logistic-regression-cox-s/18485#18485   for different defs