# How to assess GLMM performance on a new data set?

Tags: r, glmm, validation, lme4-nlme

I built a generalized linear mixed-effects model (GLMM) using `glmer` function from the `lme4` package in `r` to model species richness around aquaculture sites based on significant explanatory variables using Zuur et al. (2009) *[Mixed Effects Models and Extensions in Ecology with R](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1441927646)*. The dataset used to build the model has ~ 1000 samples and my best model is:

```r
    Mod1 <- glmer(Richness ~ Distance + Depth + Substrate + 
                   Beggiatoa + Distance*Beggiatoa + 
                   (1|Site/transect), family = poisson, 
                   data = mydata)
```

Now I have a full data set collected at different sites and I want to assess how this model performs on the new data set.

I never assessed model performance on a new data set before and my first approach would be to compare R^2 values between data sets and p-values of each explanatory variables. However, I’m sure there are much better options. **What technique would you use to assess model performance on a new data set?**

Comment: Aside $R^2$ you could consider [RMSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-mean-square_deviation) and [MAD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average_absolute_deviation) as somewhat standard metrics to show. You should also look at relevant residual plots. You mention the use of `glmer` but you don't mention what kind of response variable `Richness` is. Can you please elaborate on this further? I think this will make your question easier to understand.

Comment: @user11852 Thank you for your reply and sorry that I forgot to mention the family of the response variable. I've updated my model in my question, I'm using a Poisson distribution for the response `Richness`. I started to look into cross-validation using the `caret` package in `r`, is this something you would advice to pursue in addition to R^2, RMSE and MAD?

Comment: Sorry for the delay I never saw your comment cause my username was misspelt. Thanks for the clarifications, please see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using RMSE or even standard $R^2$ is somewhat unnatural for the case of a count response variable. Median absolute error/deviation ([MAD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_absolute_deviation)) would be definitely more natural for integer values but would not directly reflect a "*variance explained*" quantity.

Given you are particularly interested in GLMMs (instead of GLMs) I think it will be appropriate to look at something like specific for GLMMs like using the `r.squaredGLMM` function implemented in `R`'s `MuMIn` package. This is essentially the $R^2$ for GLMMs as this is described by  Nakagawa & Schielzeth on their paper on [A general and simple method for obtaining R² from generalized linear mixed-effects models](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.2041-210x.2012.00261.x/abstract). Because you are having a mixed model with fixed ($X$) and random ($Z$) covariates it makes sense to have a conditional $R^2$ as well as a marginal $R^2$.
You could also report Nagelkerke's $R^2$ (eg. using `fmsb::NagelkerkeR2`), it is somewhat standard for GL(M)Ms too.

Having mentioned the above $R^2$ quantities, please note that it is debatable whether or not $R^2$ measurements are really relevant for Poisson regression (or GLMMs in general). Pseudo-, generalised- $R^2$ come in many variants; see for example a list [here](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/mult_pkg/faq/general/Psuedo_RSquareds.htm) and an excellent discussion in this CV thread [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3559/which-pseudo-r2-measure-is-the-one-to-report-for-logistic-regression-cox-s).

My advice would be to use MAD as well as a specialised $R^2$ but *do not* focus much on the $R^2$. Reporting $p$-values in regards to a model's performance is a bit pointless....

Regarding your latest comment: Using the `caret` package and cross-validation in general is an excellent idea; you should do it. Notice though that cross-validation is best to select a model's coefficients and not to directly estimate a model's performance for unseen data. Furthermore, irrespective of the $k$ used for your $k$-fold cross-validation scheme, run at least 100 rounds/repeats of your $k$-fold procedure to ensure your results are stable. To estimate out-of-sample performance use hold-out data; a chunk of your data that you *never* touched during training. Report MAD, (specialized) $R^2$ on the model's performance on that data. See Zack's answer on the (awesome) thread [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20836/) for more details about this.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much @usεr11852, this is exactly what I was looking for! I'll need a couple days to do all your suggestions, but I can't wait to see the results on the new data set.

Comment: Cool, I am glad I could help! Good luck with the rest of your analysis!

Comment: I tried `NagelkerkeR2` from `fmsb` and `mad` from `stats` package but I get an error message saying that they don't work for S4 objects. Is it possible that they are not implemented for GLMMs yet?

Comment: I am not sure. I am very busy this week. I am will try to look it up during the weekend but in general methodologically this what you want to check. Try to ensure that the all the packages in your R installation are the latest. Also check you don't have `NA` in your model, maybe these are problematic. If the issues remains, you should raise it in StackOverflow under the tag `R`. It will be a software rather than a Stats issue (if you open this question here it will most likely be closed).

Comment: Thank you for your reply and your help. All packages are updated and I verified and there is no `NA` in the model. I'll continue to search for a solution and update here if I find the answer.

Comment: I am sorry to read that. If SO doesn't help, try the R-sig-ME mailing list.

Comment: I asked how to calculate `MAD` for my GLMM on SO and received a great answer, see link at the end. I still have to figure if I would compare `MAD` from the model on the **original data set** (_within-sample error_) to `MAD` on the **new data set** (_out-of-sample error_) but I'm getting closer to the solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39001178/how-can-i-compute-the-median-absolute-deviation-mad-for-generalized-linear-mix

Comment: @MudWarrior: Cool! Prof. Bolker's posts are always very instructive! (He is one of the authors of the current `lme4` package.)

Comment: yes I was very happy to receive the excellent answer from Prof. Bolker! By any chance, would you have any reference(s) to suggest that used `mad` in a similar context (i.e. assessing model performance on a new data set)?

Comment: Hmmm.. Davies' & Gather's Chapt. 25 "*Robust statistics*" in the *Handbook of Computational Statistics* by Gentle et al.; Hulland's et al. Chapt. 14 "*Modeling Customer Satisfaction: A Comparative Performance Evaluation of Covariance Structure Analysis Versus Partial Least Squares*" in the "*Handbook of Partial Least Squares*" by Vinzi et al. and Berk's *Statistical Learning from a Regression Perspective* (Chapt. 5 on Random Forests). In general MAD is not uncommon to use for Poisson family regressions (granted less common than RMSE).

Comment: thank you for the references, these will be very useful!