# Explaining variance with Nagelkerke's R2 - null vs full model?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, variance

I was hoping someone would be able to help me understand this - I have calculated Nagelkerke's R2 for the generalised linear model results with covariates included. ie:

```
dependent variable ~ independent variable + covariate 1 + covariate 2
```

I then calculated Nagelkerke's R2 from the null model (just the model with covariates):

```
dependent variable ~ covariate 1 + covariate 2
```

The R2 value from the full model was 0.20.  The R2 value from the null model was 0.12.  Does that mean that the independent variable in the full model explains ~ 8% of variance?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3559.

Answer (score 1):

Nagelkerke's $R^2$ is a function the likelihood of the two models, not the variance, so you cannot say anything about the variance through Nagelkerke's $R^2$. The paper *A note on a general definition of the coefficient of determination* is short and quite easy to read, and in the context of your question, the important part is the definition for Cox&Snell's $R^2$

$$ R^2 = 1-\{L(0)/L(\hat{\beta})\}^{2/n} $$

where $L(0)$ and $L(\hat{\beta})$ are the log likelihoods of the null and the fitted models. The log likelihood measures the goodness of fit of a model to the data. Nagelkerke proposed using $R^2/max(R^2)$, for reasons listed in the paper.

There is no easy and intuitive interpretation of Nagelkerke's $R^2$ that at the same time is precise - only the definition itself, which is not easy and intuitive, and vague statements about increase in goodness of fit.