# Is there an equivalent statistic to partial R-squared in logistic regression?

Tags: regression, logistic, binary-data

My dependent variable is a binary outcome(Y); therefore, I am using logistic regression. I am interested in what proportion of variance of Y is explained by the variable X1. In other words, I am interested in the unique variance of Y explained by X1 after controlling for X2 and X3.

This is the concept of partial R-squared in OLS. But I am not sure if there is an equivalent way or statistic I can use for logistic regression. Alternatively, should I use a linear probability model to obtain partial R-squared?

Comment: You could probably use the change in pseudo-R2 corresponding to removal of each predictor. Not sure if there is a straightforward formula for that, and it would depend on which pseudo-R2 you would use.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3559.  A [site search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=logistic%20regression%20R%20squared) turns up plenty of other relevant threads.